# REQUIRED triggering VALIDATION

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, validation

Okey comunity, 
I need help with my code, so this is my form code

```
<form action="input.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="input" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required=""><br>
    <input type="text" class="input lower" name="streetnumber" placeholder="Street / Number" required=""><br>
    <input type="text" class="input lower" name="city" placeholder="City" required=""><br>
    <input type="text" class="input lower" name="country" placeholder="Country" required=""><br>
    <button type="submit">Add User</button>
</form>
```

All I want to do is to ask if my 'required' in input can trigger validation. Type of validation I need basicly is NOT NULL and I want to have paragraph above each input to show up with text (This filed is a must).
If you find my question confusing please write a comment and I will provide more info.
I know I must use some JS code, but I would realy be glad if you can help me with that code and tell me what I need.

Best regards comunity

Comment: Almost all browsers (in their most recent versions) do that job for you. If an input has the `required` attribute, then the value can't be empty.

Comment: Yes, I know that but what about paragraph poping above input with text?

Comment: I tryed with oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter First Name')"
       onvalid="this.setCustomValidity('')">

Comment: But how to make paragraph pop up

Comment: Is there a way to call JS function on setCustomValidity?? And how, give me example please

Comment: Take a look at this simple validation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071566/homework-javascript-form-validation

Comment: Okey comunity,

    <p style="background-color: red">Please enter First Name</p>    
    <input type="text" class="input" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter First Name')" onvalid="this.setCustomValidity('')">

Is there a way to call JS function in this.setCustomValidity, I need that input to not be a NULL so required validatng is all I need, but i want to show this paragraph above when input is empty.

Please help me with an example, 
Thank you so much comunity !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
                var p = document.getElementById("pcountry");

                if (!country) {
                  pn.classList.add("show");
                  return false;
                } else {
                  return true;
                }
```

This is my answer